# Java Spring Boot failing to find Python Script in resources folder

Tags: java, python, spring-boot, jar

I am trying to call python Scripts(in resources) from my Java class.
This is my code `spinnet`

```
        String res = "/Scripts/Brokers/__init__.py";

        URL pathUrl = this.getClass().getResource(res);
        String path = "";
        if(pathUrl != null)
            path = pathUrl.toString();

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/python3.6", path);
```

`ProcessBuilder` is giving error `No such file or directory`.

P.S.

```
value of path = "file:/home/path-to-project/project-name/out/production/resources/Scripts/Brokers/\__init__.py"
```

Also how to include python scripts in jar file to run the project on linux server.

I am stuck with this issue since last 3 days. Please suggest.

Comment: Can you change the `value of path` to `/home/path-to-project/project-name/out/production/resources/Scripts/Brokers/\__init__.py`? without the protocol part, and try again?

Comment: There is a extra back-slash in the value of _path_. please remove it and try.

Comment: Sorry! It was for formatting purpose of question. Actual Path was without backslash.

Answer (score 1):

From java doc:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

> Starting a new process which uses the default working directory and
>   environment is easy:
>
> ```
>  Process p = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg").start();
> ```

So basically, you going to fork a sub process that will

- start a python interpreter
- with the python script that you have provided as argument.

The path to your script should be a normal path that your OS can understand, therefore you should not give a URI? like path (`protocol:address/path`).

```
if (path.contains(":"))
    path = (path.split(":"))[1];
```

Also the backslash `\` before `__init__.py` looks suspicious.

You should be able to run `ls /home/path-to-project/project-name/out/production/resources/Scripts/Brokers/__init__.py` and see the file, the same goes for `ls /usr/bin/python3.6`.

Comment: Yes I tried this. It worked on my local. But when I build jar file and ran it. Again it started giving "FileNotFoundException" . How to access python and csv files in resources in jar ?

Comment: @AwesomeBlossom: where do you run your jar file? on the same machine on or on a server?

Comment: On linux Server. Path value is like -- "/way-to-jar/data-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/Scripts/Brokers/__init__.py" on server.   It is searching in classes. but file is present in resources folder

Comment: can you do a ssh connection on this server and run: 

`ls  /home/path-to-project/project-name/out/production/resources/Scripts/Brokers/__init__.py`

and `ls /usr/bin/python3.6` and tell me the result of both commands?

Comment: Have you check that the user you are using to run the `jar` file has read access to the `__init__.py` and read/execution access on the `python`?

Comment: I am owner of that vm. I have all the access on that server. Will try storing paths in .properties file  and update here the results. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190001/discussion-between-awesomeblossom-and-allan).